# Nginx reverse proxy for drools business central workbench

Tags: drools

Issue in nginx reverse proxy for drools business central workbench. It is working fine till login page but after login it just shows loading gif which says  please wait loding application.

Answer (score 0):

THis is an issue with websocket, errai (the technology used by Drools)  and nginx.

This configuration usually solves for me:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/drools-setup/c/86XzRYrvRcY

Comment: I added this to my configuration but it still doesn't work, do you have any other solution please ?